# Работа с Yii2 image (Ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

Помогите, пожалуйста, получить остальные картинки данного портфолио при нажатии на кнопку в `foreach` через Ajax, передать обратно в `views index` и затем показать их в открываемом модальном окне (если не ошибаюсь, это метод `getImages()`).

View index:

```
<?php foreach ($portfolio_vol as $item) :?>
<?php $mainImg = $item->getImage(); ?>

    <figure class="<?=$item->category_id?> col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="#" data-id-job="<?=$item['id']?>" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalJob' class="read-job">
            <img src="<?=$mainImg->getUrl()?>" class="img_portfolio_home" alt="Img portfolio" />
            <dl>
                <dt><?=$item->name?></dt>
                <dd><?=$item->description?></dd>
            </dl>
        </a>
    </figure>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Выше выводятся работы с главной картинкой, при нажатии на кнопку:

```
<a href="#" data-id-job="<?=$item['id']?>" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalJob' class="read-job">
```

открывается модальное окно, в котором должны показаться остальные картинки методом `getImages()`, вроде.

Вот модальное окно:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModalJob" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 80%;">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title" id="name-job"></h4>
           </div>
            (где-то здесь должны выводиться картинки)
       </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

А вот наш оброботчик js:

```
 $('.read-job').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var id_job = $(this).attr('id-job');
    var data_id_job = $(this).attr('data-id-job');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/site/index',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {id_job:data_id_job},
        success: function(res){

            $('#name-job').empty();

            $('#name-job').append(res.name);

        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error!');
        }
    })
});
```

Вот контроллер прием:

```
      if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->post('id_job')){

         $id = Yii::$app->request->post('id_job');
         $res = Portfolio::findOne($id)->toArray();

         $name = trim(strip_tags($res['name']));
         $description = trim(strip_tags($res['description']));
         $date = trim(strip_tags($res['date']));

         $arr = [
            'name' => $name,
            'description' => $description,
            'date' => $date,
         ];

         return json_encode($arr);
    }
```